# Quasar SuspendExecution

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, fiber, quasar

I have a `Class` named `Foo` which calls a `non-static` method `barMethod()` of `Bar`. `Bar`extends `Fiber`.
Inside `barMethod()` there is a call to `park()`. Now which `Fiber` will be parked? `Foo` instance or `Bar` instance?
Signature of `park()` (It is defined `static` and this is the main reason for my confusion):

```
public static void park()
                 throws SuspendExecution
```

If the answer is `Foo` (It seems to be so), How can I park `Bar`? I mainly intend to `suspend (park)` `Bar` not `Foo`.
And if you provide me an answer about how to park `Bar`instance, then please tell me that since I want to park `Bar`, not `Foo`, should `barMethod()` throw `SuspendExecution`? It will not be access by any instance of `Bar`, and I don't want to park any instance of `Foo` inside this method (only `Bar`).
Please also provide answer for all the same questions about `unpark()`. Will it be applied to current `Fiber` (`Foo` instance in this case) or it affects `Bar` instance? If latter, then how can I unpark `Bar` instance, not `Foo` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Just like with threads, a fiber can only park itself. A call to `park` suspends the currently executing fiber. The class where the current method is defined is completely irrelevant. So the answer to your question of "which fiber will be parked, Bar or Foo", is "whichever fiber is currently executing". It can be the Bar instance, the Foo instance, or some other fiber altogether.

Just like with `Thread`, the only `Fiber` method that is ever worth overriding is `run`. Subclassing `Fiber` (or `Thread`) for any other reason makes no sense. It's best if you think of fibers and threads as being exactly the same idea, implemented in two different ways. A `Thread` is a thread implemented by the OS, and `Fiber` is a (lighweight) thread implemented in the JVM, but they both behave essentially the same.

Finally, `park` and `unpark` are a low-level API (just like `LockSupport.park/unpark` that do the same for plain threads), and unless you're writing a new concurrency mechanism (like a new kind of lock) you shouldn't use them directly. Instead, use any of the higher-level fiber synchronization APIs, like channels, locks etc..

Answer (score -1):

quasar discourages calling park and unpark directly

kilim is a similar tool that provides Fiber.yield (equivalent to park) and you can run a task directly. so i think it can do what you are looking for

in your example, barMethod should be marked as Pausable, but the calling method doesn't need to be

we recently did a pre-release of kilim 2.0. in particular, you should look at the Continuation class and the XorShift example

https://github.com/nqzero/kilim